# Extracting common jest mock into util file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I've gone through the official Jest docs around manual mocking but I can't quite make sense of it.

I have a file that exports an object of computed values

utils.js

```
export const getCalculatedValues = (stuff) => ({
   val1: 'val1',
   val2: 'val2',
   ...
});
```

I am then using this within several other files that I am attempting to test - For example:

usage.js

```
import {getCalculatedValues} from './utils';

export const doSomething = () => getCalculatedValues('some-val');
```

So far, I have managed to mock the original `getCalculatedValues`

usage.test.js

```
jest.mock('./utils', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  getCalculatedValues: {
    val1: 123,
    val2: 321,
    ...
  }
}));


// Assume this passes ;-)
it('Should return mock values', () => {
    const res = doSomething();
    expect(res.val1).toEqual(123);
});
```

As mentioned previously, I am using `getCalculatedValues` in several different files which would mean that I am needing to perform the `jest.mock` of it within each of their test files, which is a lot of duplication.

I am trying to get my head around the "manual mocking" aspect of Jest but I can't seem to understand what I should be doing...

I understand that I should create a file within a `__mocks__` directory, but from there, I'm not entirely sure what should go in that file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import the file that you are trying to mock on the global level of the test server.

```
import utils from "../src/utils.js";
```

Comment: Where would this go, sorry?

Comment: In the file jest.config.js you are going to have an attribute 
**setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./tests/globalSetup.ts"],**
this indicates that this file is going to run before starting test cases you can add that in the top of that file with imports

Comment: And the goal there is to import the original file itself, not any sort of mocked version?

Comment: I managed to solve it. I ended up doing my `jest.mock('../src/urils')` in the `jest.config.js` file and all worked the same. Saves me from replicating that line. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I feel my confusion came from the official Jest docs around the issue as they showed performing a manual mock on both a dependency and also a file at the same time.

I took a bit of inspiration from a Youtube tutorial I saw that showed performing a manual mock on a file only.

So as the docs say, you must create a mock for the thing you're attempting to mock within the same directory level but within its own `__mocks__` directory.

So for me, say we had a file structure like

```
.
└── src/
    ├── utils/
    │   └── utils.js
    └── other-files/
        ├── usage.js
        └── usage.test.js
```

given we are wanting to mock the functionality within `/src/utils/utils.js` and not in `/other-files/usage` we should create the `__mocks__` directory and `__mocks__/utils.js` within `/src/utils`

```
.
└── src/
    ├── utils/
    │   ├── __mocks__/
    │   │   └── utils.js
    │   └── utils.js
    └── other-files/
        ├── usage.js
        └── usage.test.js
```

The content of `/__mocks__/utils.js` should mirror the contents of the original file you are mocking. At least, the parts you want to mock and return the mock value you are looking for.

****mocks**/utils.js**

```
export const getCalculatedValues = (stuff) => ({
   val1: 'mocked-val1',
   val2: 'mocked-val2',
   ...
});
```

Then, we just have to mock it within the `/other-files/usage.test.js` file

```
jest.mock('../utils/utils');

// Assume this passes ;-)
it('Should return mock values', () => {
    const res = doSomething();
    expect(res.val1).toEqual(123);
});
```

And that should be it!

A good check is to do a `console.log` of the value you are wanting to check.